# Android Studio error launching emulator: permission denied (on Mac OSX)

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, emulation, osx-yosemite

When I try to launch the emulator on Android Studio(1.5.1) on my Mac OSX(Yosemite) I get this error:

```
Error launching emulator: Cannot run program "/Users/S/Library/Android/sdk/tools/emulator": error=13, Permission denied
```

What is causing this and how can I solve it?

Comment: As what user are you running Android Studio, and does this user have permissions on that directory?

Comment: @unicorn2 I am logged in as admin and have the permission to read and write to that directory

Answer (score 0):

Try to append $ANDROID_HOME/emulator:$ANDROID_HOME/tools in your .
It will somehow looks like export **PATH=$M2_HOME/bin:$ANDROID_HOME:$ANDROID_HOME/emulator:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$PATH**
Make sure **$ANDROID_HOME/emulator comes before $ANDROID_HOME/tools**
reload your bash profile.

Now try to run command which emulator in terminal.
Run command in terminal to open emulator **emulator -avd Pixel_4_API_30**